# using preg_match_all to find patterns, don't include pattern deliminator in matchs

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'm matching patterns with reg_ex as in

```
$Structure = 'C:N:X:A:V:T:J:N:G:T:N:N:C:J:N:C:A:J:N:.:';
preg_match_all('/(T:|G:|L:|D:).*?(G:|i:|X:|\.:)/', $Structure, $arr, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

the results I get are

```
T:J:N:G: , T:N:N:C:J:N:C:A:J:N:.:
```

How can I modify the query so that the deliminator (G:|i:|X:|.:) of the match is not included in the find, but will bu used in the next search. In other words make the result look as bellow:

```
T:J:N: , G:T:N:N:C:J:N:C:A:J:N:
```

instead?

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible by [lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), with the following syntax:

```
(?=G:|i:|X:|\.:)
```

That will not consume the piece that matches the regex.

On a side note, the delimiter means the slashes that you have enclosing your regex and not the capturing group you have.

Comment: I don't think he meant regex delimiter. He meant the delimiter within his specific string (T: and G:, for example).

Comment: I see. I just assumed that to be part of the string he was matching for, but if it holds some sort of special meaning...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, instead of making your 2nd capturing group consume the input, turn it into a positive lookahead:

```
/(T:|G:|L:|D:).*?(?=(?:G:|i:|X:|\.:))/
```

Now, instead of matching (and consuming) the delimiter, this:

```
(?=(?:G:|i:|X:|\.:))
```

States that the regex must assert that the delimiter is present from the current point forward, i.e. a positive lookahead.

This [results in](http://viper-7.com/lTxB6M):

```
"T:J:N:, G:T:N:N:C:J:N:C:A:J:N:"
```